# Issue : Including "Paper.js"

Tags: javascript, paperjs

i'm want to try paper.js so i make an html file like this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PAPERJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="paper-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/paperscript" src="myscript.js" canvas="myCanvas">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>paper js :</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

But it don't recognize the type="text/paperscript"

my file myscipt.js only contain this :

```
var myBall = new Path.Circle(new Point(70, 70), 50);
myBall.fillColor = 'tomato';
```

after this declaration nothing is happening in my html file when i try it :

```
<script type="text/paperscript" src="myscript.js" canvas="myCanvas">
```

Comment: @Shintu Joseph Thanks i got it ! I got another issue then, in my js file then i try to write something to see if actually my html file 'call' the javascript file so i do a `document.write("test");` at the first line of my javascript but when i test it it only print my `<h1></h1>` flag and not the javascript after this one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the "text/paperscript" type you must use "paper-full" not "paper-core". The paper-core file does not include the paperscript interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you missed the `</script>` end tag

Scripts that have different type other than `text/javascript` are not parsed by the html parser in browser but the paperscript type,you included are the custom type that the JS plugin for which you are including that particular type will run through your dom and use the content inside that file. (To be clearer)